# Testing for a button's disabled state in React

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs

I have a simple component that I want to test using React and ReactUtils.

```
var TextConfirmButton = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      inputText: '',
      confirmText: this.props.confirmText,
      buttonEnabled: false,
      inputEnabled: true
    }
  },

  handleChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({ inputText: event.target.value });
  },

  handleConfirm: function() {
    this.props.onConfirmClick();
    // When user clicks the confirm button, disable both the input and button.
    this.setState({ buttonEnabled: false, inputEnabled: false });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} disabled={!this.state.inputEnabled} type='text' ref='text' placeholder={this.state.confirmText} />
        <button onClick={this.handleConfirm} disabled={this.state.inputText !== this.state.confirmText} className='btn btn-danger'>Delete</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
})
```

Is there a way to test for a button's disabled state?

I've attempted:

```
var TestUtils = React.addons.TestUtils;

describe('TextConfirmButton', function () {
  it('starts with confirm button disabled', function () {
    var onConfirmClick = function() {
      console.log("Confirm click");
    }

    var textConfirmButton = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <TextConfirmButton confirmText="example" onConfirmClick={this.onConfirmClick} />
    );

    var textConfirmButtonNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(textConfirmButton);

    expect(textConfirmButtonNode.disabled).toEqual('disabled');
  });
});
```

But the test fails, with the error: `textConfirmButtonNode.disabled undefined`. So `.disabled` is obviously the wrong way to go about this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: All I can comment is that if you have the DOMNode then `.disabled` is the correct way to check, are you sure that `textConfirmButtonNode` is the DOMNode? `console.dir(textConfirmButtonNode)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [TestUtils#findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#findrendereddomcomponentwithtag) in order to be able to query the DOM generated by TestUtils.

```
var textConfirmButtonNode = 
TestUtils.findRenderedDOMComponentWithTag(textConfirmButton, 'button');

expect(textConfirmButtonNode.disabled).toEqual(true);
```

Comment: With this method, the test passes as expected. I wonder why it doesn't work with whatever `childNodes[1]` returns.

Answer (score 1):

`textConfirmButtonNode` references the outermost `div` in your `render()` function.  Unless it has an attribute of `disabled`, it isn't surprising that it is returning undefined.

My guess is that you were looking for a DOM node that references the actual `button`.

```
var textConfirmButtonNode = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(textConfirmButton);
var renderedButtonNode = textConfirmButtonNode.childNodes[1];

expect(renderedButtonNode.disabled).toEqual('disabled');
```

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. But I'm getting `Error: Expected false to equal true.` - Shouldn't `disabled` be true seeing my component code above? It should start out disabled and I see that visually when I browse my website.

Comment: I just copied the code you posted above, but I'd change `toEqual('disabled')` to `toEqual(true)`, not sure if that fixes the issue though